# Git - Working with nested submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have the following git repositories

- `Vector`
- `Random`
- `String`

String relies on Vector, and adds it as a submodule.
Vector submodules Random. Random has no dependencies.

- `Module: Random`
- `Module: Vector`

  - `Submodule: Random`
- `Module: String`

  - `Submodule: Vector`

    - `Submodule: Random`

When I change something inside of `Random` submodule inside of `Vector`, (NOT the actual module `Random`), it does not automatically update `Module: Random` or the other `Submodule Random`'s that exist elsewhere.

When I change something inside of `Vector` (the module), it does not update the `Vector` in `String`. If I visit the repository for `String`, and type `git pull`, it claims everything is up to date. If I `cd` inside of `submodule Vector`  and type `git pull`, only THEN does it actually update my `submodule Vector`. Ontop of that it wants me to commit changes to the `String` repository, **even though nothing has changed inside of `String`**.

What if I have a repository with 50 submodules? My submodules are going to be changing **constantly** and I don't want to have to not only pull every single time I want to touch my project but also commit that pull since it was the submodules that changed. There's got to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: As part of the infrastructure, git keeps the commit sha of where you are using the submodule (i.e. why you need to commit in the parent when you update the child - you changed what *commit* of the submodule is being used!). This is because every "client" of that repository could be using it at a different version. This becomes important where you don't want to change or update one client as you add new features (and bugs), but want others to use the latest.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [`git pull` options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_options), you should use, from String (the main parent repo) a:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules=yes
git submodule update --recursive
```

> On top of that it wants me to commit changes to the `String` repository, even though nothing has changed inside of `String`.

Sure something has changed: the gitlink (special entry in the repo index) of the submodule `Vector`.

If you don't want to do that every time you have to refresh the content of `String`, and just want to do a simple regular `git pull`, do only once:

```
git config --global fetch.recurseSubmodules true
```

And you can [automate the submodule update as a post-checkout hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37383406/6309).

Similarly, a simple git push from String would also push any changed submodule, provided you set once:

```
git config --global push.recurseSubmodules true
```

Comment: Do I need  to do those two lines **every time** I work on `String`? My sub-modules are bound to constantly be changing so i guess in order to keep things working I need to pull like that before any type work?

Comment: @Hatefiend No, you can automate/configure those steps in order to have to do only a simple basic `git pull` from `String`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Inside of my `module Vector`, I did `git pull --recurse-submodules=yes` and it did correctly notice that `Random` was changed and so it said `Fetching submodule random from...`. After that, I typed `git submodule update --recursive` and nothing appeared to have happened. I `cd`'ed inside of `submodule Random` and indeed my changes were not there. I did `git status` and it said I was behind by one commit. I did a regular `git pull` and it correctly grabbed the changes. Any ideas why it didn't work?

Comment: @Hatefiend did you add and commit in String when you changed Random? Because otherwise, you need to configure Random to follow a branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309. Then the command to automate becomes: `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote`. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24635535/6309

Comment: @Hatefiend Note: if your submodules changes are always on their respective master branch, you only need `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote`: no special configuration required for those submodules. As to why, see a detailled use case in http://stackoverflow.com/q/37879715/6309